# Ansible: How to convert/filter list into dictionary based on specific word from list

Tags: ansible

I have one list and need  to convert/filter that list into dictionary  based on specific word from list
**List:input**

```
 [
        "[profile appdev]\r\nArn: aaa.dev:333:iam\r\nRegion: ap.southeast2\r\n\r\n",
        "[profile applead]\r\nArn: aaa.techlead:333:iam\r\nRegion: ap.southeast2\r\n\r\n",
        "[profile appprod]\r\nArn: aaa.techlead:333:iam\r\nRegion: ap.southeast2\r\n\r\n",
        "[profile apppadmin]\r\nArn: aaa.techlead:333:iam\r\nRegion: ap.southeast2\r\n\r\n",
        "[profile appsupport]\r\nArn: aaa.dev:333:iam\r\nRegion: ap.southeast2\r\n\r\n",
        "[profile appguest]\r\nArn: aaa.techlead:433:iam\r\nRegion: ap.southeast3"
 ]
```

**dictionary  :output**

```
{
[profile appdev]:"profile appdev]\r\nArn: aaa.dev:333:iam\r\nRegion: ap.southeast2\r\n\r\n",
[profile applead]:"[profile applead]\r\nArn: aaa.techlead:333:iam\r\nRegion: ap.southeast2\r\n\r\n"
[profile appprod]:"[profile appprod]\r\nArn: aaa.techlead:333:iam\r\nRegion: ap.southeast2\r\n\r\n",
[profile apppadmin]:"[profile apppadmin]\r\nArn: aaa.techlead:333:iam\r\nRegion: ap.southeast2\r\n\r\n",
[profile appsupport]:"[profile appsupport]\r\nArn: aaa.dev:333:iam\r\nRegion: ap.southeast2\r\n\r\n",
[profile appguest]:"[profile appguest]\r\nArn: aaa.techlead:433:iam\r\nRegion: ap.southeast3"
}
```

Is it possible to achieve in Ansible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        dict1: "{{ dict(keys|zip(list1)) }}"
      vars:
        regex: '(\[.*\])(.*)'
        replace: '\1'
        keys: "{{ list1|map('regex_replace', regex, replace)|list }}"
```

Given the list in the variable *list1* create a list of keys. For example, use *map* and *regex_replace* to create the list *keys*. Then use *dict* and *zip* to create the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for very prompt response and i will try your approach

Comment: With Slight modification in regex as below, your approach works fine, thank you so much

regex: '(\[.*\])[\w\W]+$'